# jQuery offset().top not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a div to stick once it is scrolled out of view.

```
var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();

jQ(document).ready(function() {

  var win = jQ(window);
  var navTop = jQ('#navbar').offset().top;

  win.scroll(function() {
    jQ('#navbar').toggleClass('sticky', win.scrollTop() > navTop);
  });

});
```

The problem is that with this code, navTop is not calculated correctly. If I calculate navTop in the scroll function it works as expected but with a horrible flickering effect which I assume is due to recalculating the value many times.

Why does it not calculate the value correctly after document is loaded?

Comment: You could throttle it, check here http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/. Or check if it's already sticky. Also did you know? `jQuery(function($){ //use $ }`

Comment: There's no flickering when I try it -> http://jsfiddle.net/uGkHx/

Comment: You should not calculate navTop in the scroll function, because you only need to log the initial position of the element to determine if it has been scrolled out of view. I have checked your code in a fiddle, and it seems to work just fine... http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/sE4GU/

Comment: @Terry I had a look at the fiddle and yes it works fine. Could it be flickering because I have a lot of styling applied to the navbar?

Comment: I wouldn't suspect the amount of styling added would have affected the rendering speed of the element in your browser, unless you're on a very slow machine, or on mobile (but anyway, `position: fixed` is problematic on many mobile browsers so you might want to selectively deactivate it)

Comment: @Terry This will only be a feature on a desktop browser. It seems correct to calculate the navTop outside the scroll func but why is it giving me the wrong value? In this case the value calculated is 30px but if I do the same thing after scrolling it changes to the correct value of 308px

Comment: Do you have other dynamically added elements that is inserted between the declaration of the navTop variable and the scroll function? Also, are there any functions between two, in your JS file, that changes the height, adds/removes content around the #navBar element?

Comment: @Terry No this is the only js code I've written and it is written exactly as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix I used for this problem was to fire another scroll event once to calculate the navTop variable and it works ok now.

Final Code:

```
var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();

jQ(document).ready(function() {

  var win = jQ(window);
  var navTop;

  jQ(document).one("scroll", function() {

    navTop = jQ('#header').offset().top;

  });

  win.scroll(function() {

    jQ('#navbar').toggleClass('sticky', win.scrollTop() > navTop);

  });

});
```